# communication between two people without refresh the page message should be display each other

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**communication between two people without refresh the page message should be display each other,but below code after refresh only display the message each other please help me any one**

**view page**

```
<div id="chat_log"> 

                                    <?php foreach ($customer_to_supplier as $row) { ?> 
                                        <?php
                                        if ($row->From == 'customer') {
                                            ?>
                                            <div class="row msg_container base_sent active">
                                                <div class="col-md-1">

                                                    <?php if (empty($roww->buyer[0]) || empty($roww->buyer)) { ?>
                                                        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/default.jpg" class="img-circle" width="30px" height="30px"/>

                                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                                        <img src="<?php echo 'data:image;base64,' . $roww->buyer; ?>" class="img-circle" width="30px" height="30px"/>

                                                    <?php } ?>

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-11 col-xs-11">
                                                    <div class="messages msg_sent">

                                                        <?php $timestamp1 = strtotime($row->msg_sent_time); ?>
                                                        <?php $mesgtimming = date(' D-h:i A', $timestamp1); ?>
                                                        <p>
                                                            <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="<?php echo $mesgtimming; ?>"><?php echo $row->message; ?> </a>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php } else { ?>
                                            <div class="row msg_container base_receive">

                                                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                                                    <div class="messages msg_receive">

                                                        <?php $timestamp1 = strtotime($row->msg_sent_time); ?>
                                                        <?php $mesgtimming = date(' D-h:i A', $timestamp1); ?>
                                                        <p>
                                                            <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="left" title="<?php echo $mesgtimming; ?>"><?php echo $row->message; ?> </a>
                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ?>

                                </div>

 <form class="form-horizontal msg_fixed_bottom send_message_form" id="data_form"  method="POST" role="form" action="#"> 
                                <div class="panel-footer" id="myForm" >
                                    <div class="input-group submit_group">

                                        <input type ="hidden" name="suppid" id="suppid" value="<?php echo $row->supplier_id; ?>" class="form-control" />
                                        <input type ="hidden" name="proid" id="proid" value="<?php echo $row->product_id; ?>" class="form-control" />
                                        <input type ="hidden" name="custid" id="custid" value="<?php echo $row->Customer_id; ?>" class="form-control" />

                                        <input id="messagee" name="messagee" type="text" class="form-control input-sm chat_input" placeholder="Write your message here..." />


                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="submit" name="submit">Send</button>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

**controller**

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
        $data['customer_to_supplier'] = $this->Profile_model->customer_to_supply($id);
        $this->load->view('messageview', $data);
```

**Model**

```
public function customer_to_supply($id) {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('communication');
    $this->db->join('supplier_otherdetails', 'supplier_otherdetails.supplierid_fk = communication.supplier_id');
    //$this->db->join('customer_otherdetails','communication.Customer_id=customer_otherdetails.customerid_fk');
    $this->db->join('customer_registration', 'communication.Customer_id=customer_registration.id');

    $array = array('communication.product_id' => $id, 'communication.supplier_id' => $this->session->id);
    $this->db->where($array);
    $this->db->order_by("msg_sent_time");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $results = [];
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        $results = $query->result();
    }
    return $results;
}
```

**script**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#data_form').on('submit', function (e) {

                    var form_data = $(this).serialize();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/supplier_communication',
                        data: form_data,
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            scrollDown();
                            var message = $("#messagee").val();

//                           $('#chat_log').append('<div class="row msg_container base_sent"><div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10"><div class="messages msg_sent"><p>' + message + '</p></div></div></div>');
                            $('#chat_log').append('<div class="row msg_container base_sent active"><div class="row msg_container base_receive"><div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p><a>' + message + '</a></p></div></div></div></div>');

                            $('#messagee').val('');

                        },
                        error: function ()
                        {
                            alert('failed');
                        }
                    });

                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                scrollDown();
                function scrollDown() {
                    $('.msg_container_base').animate({scrollTop: $('.msg_container_base').prop("scrollHeight")}, 200);
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: May be use ajax for that

Comment: Person A and Person B communication between each other after refresh only chat message displaying without refresh message should be display how i am not getting,if you possible give me example @wolfgang1983

Comment: You need to use either long pooling or websockets to achieve that. https://github.com/kishor10d/CodeIgniter-Ratchet-Websocket check this repository.

Comment: I am not getting @kishor10d

Comment: websocket is a concept where two way communication is possible. When you send any message to server, it broadcast the same message to connected clients. You can control the client who can receive the message.

Comment: if you possible modify my code @kishor10d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your model `customer_to_supply()` function change with following code

```
public function customer_to_supply($id, $time = null, $type = null) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('communication');
    $this->db->join('supplier_otherdetails', 'supplier_otherdetails.supplierid_fk = communication.supplier_id');
    $this->db->join('customer_registration', 'communication.Customer_id=customer_registration.id');

    $array = array('communication.product_id' => $id, 'communication.supplier_id' => $this->session->id);
    $this->db->where($array);

    if($time != '')
        $this->db->where('unix_timestamp(msg_sent_time) >', $time, false );

    if($type != '')
        $this->db->where('From', $type );

    $this->db->order_by("msg_sent_time");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $results = [];
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        $results = $query->result();
    }
    return $results;
}
```

and in your **script** add following code

```
var last_time = $("#last-time").val();
getMessages = function() {
    var self = this;
    console.log(last_time);
    var url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Profile_cntrl/get_message/customer/<?=$_GET['id']?>/'+last_time;
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        console.debug(data);
        if(data.status) {
            last_time = data.next_time;
            $("#last-time").val(data.next_time);
            $('#chat_log').append(data.message);
            scrollDown(); 
        }

        setTimeout(function(){
            getMessages();
        }, 5000);
    });
}
getMessages();
```

In your **view** page. You have to do some alteration as follow

1. Add `$msg_sent_time = '';` before foreach
2. Add `$msg_sent_time = $row->msg_sent_time;` after foreach open
3. Add Following html code after foreach function close

`<input id="last-time" value="<?=strtotime($msg_sent_time);?>">`

Answer (score 0):

For a chat and similar needs, there is Laravel + Echo npm package

See here: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo